# Get count of foreign key from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions, correlated-subquery

I have 3 tables, with Table B & C referencing Table A via Foreign Key. I want to write a query in PostgreSQL to get all ids from A and also their total occurrences from B & C.

```
   a      |     b      |     c
-----------------------------------    
id | txt  |  id | a_id |  id | a_id  
---+----  |  ---+----- |  ---+------ 
1  |  a   |  1  |  1   |  1  |  3    
2  |  b   |  2  |  1   |  2  |  4    
3  |  c   |  3  |  3   |  3  |  4    
4  |  d   |  4  |  4   |  4  |  4
```

Output desired (just the id from A & total count in B & C) :

```
id | Count
---+-------  
1  |  2      -- twice in B
2  |  0      -- occurs nowhere
3  |  2      -- once in B & once in C
4  |  4      -- once in B & thrice in C
```

SQL so far [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/25c22/2/0) :

```
SELECT a_id, COUNT(a_id)
FROM
( SELECT a_id FROM b
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a_id FROM c
) AS union_table
GROUP BY a_id
```

The query I wrote fetches from B & C and counts the occurrences. But if the key doesn't occur in B or C, it doesn't show up in the output (e.g. id=2 in output). How can I start my selection from table A & join/union B & C to get the desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the query involves large parts of `b` and / or `c` it is more efficient to aggregate first and join later.
I expect these two variants to be considerably faster:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
     , COALESCE(b.ct, 0) + COALESCE(c.ct, 0) AS bc_ct
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT a_id, count(*) AS ct FROM b GROUP BY 1) b USING (a_id)
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT a_id, count(*) AS ct FROM c GROUP BY 1) c USING (a_id);
```

You need to account for the possibility that some `a_id` are not present at all in `a` and / or `b`. `count()` never returns `NULL`, but that's cold comfort in the face of `LEFT JOIN`, which leaves you with `NULL` values for missing rows nonetheless. You *must* prepare for `NULL`. Use **[`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)**.

Or UNION ALL `a_id` from both tables, aggregate, *then* JOIN:

```sql
SELECT a.id
     , COALESCE(ct.bc_ct, 0) AS bc_ct
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT a_id, count(*) AS bc_ct
   FROM (
      SELECT a_id FROM b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a_id FROM c
      ) bc
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) ct USING (a_id);
```

Probably slower. But still faster than solutions presented so far. And you could do without `COALESCE()` and still not loose any rows. You might get occasional `NULL` values for `bc_ct`, in this case.

Comment: Why do you say your 2nd option is `probably slower`? It has less JOINS, shouldn't it be faster?

Comment: @click I'm not an expert with PostgreSQL (far from it), but probably using a aggregate function like `GROUP BY` will indeed be slower. But thinking better about it, I don't really get why Erwin's first query is should be faster than my answer (I believe both would have similar execution plans in databases like Oracle and SQL Server), but I *guess* he knows what he is talking about.

Comment: @click: the number of joins is just one of many factors. It all depends on cardinalities and data distribution (among others). That's why I talk about typical cases and probabilities. You have to test with your *actual* scenario to know for sure. The first query typically hits a sweet spot between simplicity and effectiveness.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id) +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c WHERE c.a_id = a.id)
FROM
    a
```

Comment: This is neat. I didn't know you can have select statements inside select & add them simply.

Comment: @click: For more than a handful of `a_id` values, **[correlated subqueries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)** (that's the term) are typically *slower* than alternative solutions. Postgres needs to run one subquery per `a_id` value. Be sure to test with a realistic set of data.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to one from @ErwinBrandstetter for performance. But for smaller tables, this wins for compactness. I'll visit this again when I have more data to compare.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure Erwin is right. I was not concerned about giving a faster (or even *better*) answer, just an alternative way of getting the same result set.

Answer (score 2):

Use left join with a subquery:

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(x.id)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, a_id FROM b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, a_id FROM c
) x ON (a.id = x.a_id)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: Wish I could accept both the answers. When I've more data, I'll come & revisit this to find which performs better but it appears that the other one avoids JOIN and might be faster.

Comment: There is even a third possible solution.